# How to deal with a huge number of intents using DialogFlow?

Tags: python, flask, dialogflow-es

I created a relational database, that has multiple table. For example, in the first table are all the cars available, in the second table the available models of each car and in the third table the price of each model.
I need to use this with Google Dialogflow Chatbot.
My question is that If I want to create intents for each car and for each model manually, it'll end up having hundreds of intents, which I do believe is not a professional way. So, what should I do in this situation.
The flow for example would be like this:

1. **User:** What cars are available?
   **Prompt:** "displays a list of all the cars"
2. **User:** I want the models of BMW
   **Prompt:** "displays a list of all the models available of BMW"
3. **User:** I want the price of Model XXXX
   **Prompt:** "Displays the price of this model"

I need help in this.

I've tried creating manually the intents, but I'm stuck due to the huge number of intents. I expect a more professional way to handle these intents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you make all of intent completely rely on cars, the amount of intent will explode.

How about creating the 3 intents listed below that handle car, model, price respectively.

I hope this help you.

---

## Dialogflow setting

### Entities

| entity name | reference value | synonyms |
| --- | --- | --- |
| car | car | cars, vehicle |
| company | BMW | bmw |
|  | Mercedes-Benz | mercedes, benz |
|  | Nissan | nissan |
| model | XXXX | xxxx |

### Intents

| intent name | entity | context in | context out |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| car intent | @car | - | car |
| company intent | @company | car | company |
| model intent | @model | company | model |

---

## Each Intent behavior

### car intent

- description
  When user wants to see cars, this intent shows cars.
- utterance and entities

| utterance | entity name | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| What cars are available? | @car | cars |

- pseudo SQL for prompt

```
SELECT car_name FROM car_table;
```

### company intent

- description
  When user says the car company, this intent shows models.
- utterance and entities

| utterance | entity name | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| I want the models of BMW | @company | BMW |

- pseudo SQL for prompt

```
SELECT model_name FROM model_table WHERE comapny_name = '[@company]';
```

### model intent

- description
  When user says anything about model, this intent shows the price of model.
- utterance and entities

| utterance | entity name | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| I want the price of model XXXX | @model | XXXX |

- pseudo SQL for prompt

```
SELECT price FROM price_of_each_model_table WHERE model_name = '[@model]';
```